# How to detect webcam is being used by another application in js/ts for chrome browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I wan't to detect only on chrome browser. I have tried using below code but not working properly.

```
let mediaStreamTrack = result.getVideoTracks()[0];

if (mediaStreamTrack && typeof mediaStreamTrack != "undefined") {
  mediaStreamTrack.onended = function () {//for Chrome.                    
    alert("Webcam is busy");
  }
}
```